# Web Scraping - Can't take a text value

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape through python, already tried:

- bs4, selenium, requests, helium. [Included classes, tags, xpath, etc]..

Though I never had this kind of issue, maybe I'm doing something wrong.
I just can't take this text value: **G120-5**, shown in the image bellow:

Link: https://www.kavak.com/br/carros-usados-100550

If someone can do it, please let me know. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data you see is loaded from external URL. You can use `requests` module to simulate it:

```py
import json
import requests


# url = "https://www.kavak.com/br/carros-usados-100550"
car_id = "100550"  # <-- this is the id from URL
api_url = (
    f"https://api.kavak.services/services-common/inventory/{car_id}/dynamic"
)

headers = {
    "kavak-country-id": "76",
    "kavak-region-id": "4",
    "kavak-subsidiary-id": "3",
}

data = requests.get(api_url, headers=headers).json()
# uncomment to print all data:
# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

print(data["data"]["coordinate"])
```

Prints:

```
G120-5
```

Comment: Do you mind explain what you did? 
For example, what is this line:
 f"https://api.kavak.services/services-common/inventory/{car_id}/dynamic
And the headers, how/where did you find the api.kavak.services

Comment: @renan `f"https://api.kavak.services/services-common/inventory/{car_id}/dynamic"` is called f-string in Python (you can look it up here on StackOverflow). The correct headers I found in Firefox Developer Tools -> Network Tab (Chrome has something similar) - there are all requests the page is doing.